# When do improper linear models get robustly beautiful?

Tags: regression, references, linear-model, robust

Are improper linear models used in practice or are they some kind of curiosity described from time to time in scientific journals? If so, in what areas are they used? When would they be useful?

They are based on linear regression

$$ y = a + b \sum_i w_i x_i + \varepsilon $$

but $w_j$'s are *not* coefficients estimated in the model, but are

- equal for each variable $w_i = 1$ ([unit-weighted regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit-weighted_regression)),
- based on correlations $w_i = \rho(y, x_i)$ (Dana and Dawes, 2004),
- chosen randomly (Dawes, 1979),
- $-1$ for variables negatively related to $y$, $1$ for variables positively related to $y$ (Wainer, 1976).

I also saw features being $z$-scaled and the output being weighted using simple linear regression

$$ y = a + b v + \varepsilon $$

where $v = \sum w_i x$, and can be simply estimated using OLS regression.

**References:**
Dawes, Robyn M. (1979). [The robust beauty of improper linear models in decision making](https://www.cmu.edu/dietrich/sds/docs/dawes/the-robust-beauty-of-improper-linear-models-in-decision-making.pdf). *American Psychologist, 34,* 571-582.

Graefe, A. (2015). [Improving forecasts using equally weighted predictors](http://andrewgelman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Graefe-2013-Improving-forecasts-using-equally-weighted-predictors-JBR.pdf). *Journal of Business Research, 68*(8), 1792-1799.

Wainer, Howard (1976). [Estimating coefficients in linear models: It don't make no nevermind](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/%7Ehwainer/Readings/Wainer_Estimating%20Coefficients%20in%20Linear%20Models.pdf). *Psychological Bulletin 83*(2), 213.

Dana, J. and Dawes, R.M. (2004). [The Superiority of Simple Alternatives to Regression for Social Science Predictions](http://hbanaszak.mjr.uw.edu.pl/TempTxt/3701356.pdf). *Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics, 29*(3), 317-331.

Comment: In what sense would the statistics derived from these models be "incorrect"?

Comment: When the $w_i$s are pre-specified & $b$ estimated, this is just data reduction carried out on the predictors - common enough in various forms (see e.g. the Glasgow Coma Scale & the Charlson Co-morbidity Index) - which won't affect the validity of inference in the usual OLS framework. When $y$ is used to determine the $w_i$s, the standard errors &c. will be out, in the optimistic direction I'd think.

Comment: @Scortchi if you are willing to extend your comment I'd be interested in hearing more. The approach is pretty "obvious", but exactly because of that it is hard to find detailed consideration of it.

Comment: It wasn't an informed comment - the papers are still on my "to read" pile. I just wondered:-"why 'improper'?". It's not unusual for a predictor to be a linear combination of other variables - an average of several measurements, a principal component score, a prediction from another regression, the level from an exponentially smoothed time series, or a calculated value from a well-established or an ad hoc index. Not estimating the weights from the response spares degrees of freedom, helping to avoid over-fitting with smaller sample sizes.

Comment: @Scortchi "improper" is referring to Dawes (1979) paper - "improper" because weights are constant, guessed or random, rather than estimated (i.e. optimal).

Comment: In e.g. [Beddhu (2000), "A simple comorbidity scale predicts clinical outcomes and costs in dialysis patients" Am. J. Med., **108**, 8](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10856407) the model equation has the same form as yours where the $x_i$s are defined as the indicator variables for diabetes, lymphoma, & c., & the $w_i$s are pre-specified. I suppose what I'm saying is that the distinction between "improper" & "proper" regression models seems to rest on the notion of a God-given set of $x_i$s, for each of which a "proper" model would estimate a coefficient.

Comment: When $w_i = \rho(y, x_i)$, & if $\rho$ were estimated from the same data the model is fit to, that'd be quite a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 1):

In effect, it seems to me this is an assortment of assumed covariance structures. In other words, this is a type of Bayesian prior modelling.

This gains in robustness over an ordinary MLR procedure because the number of parameters ($\downarrow$df) is reduced, and introduces inaccuracy because of augmented [omitted variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias), OVB. Because of the OVB, the slope is flattened, $|\hat\beta|<|\beta|$, the coefficient of determination is reduced $\hat{R}^2<R^2$.

My personal experience is that the superior to the Bayesian approach is to use better modelling; transform parameters, use other norms, and/or use nonlinear methods. That is, once the physics of the problem and the methods are properly explored and co-ordinated, the F statistics, coefficient of determination, etc. improve rather than degrade.