# Only allowing coefficients to be -1, 0, 1 for predicting a continuous variable

Tags: machine-learning, regression-coefficients

I want to fit a regression model (well, actually the y variable is continuous, I don't care about the model), and I'm wondering if there is a way to constrain all coefficients to be -1, 0 or 1. It almost feels like some kind of a rule system.

Does anyone know how to do this? Preferably a solution in Python :)

Comment: Genetic algorithms work well under many different types of constraints, perhaps you could look into them.

Comment: How many coefficients do you have? Since each can only have 3 possible values, you might be able to just do an exhaustive search across all possible combinations, as long as the number of coefficients isn't too high.

Comment: @RubenvanBergen I do not know yet, but I estimate around 10-100k (text + ngram).

Comment: @Hugh I was also going to be writing down genetic algorithm, but didn't want to influence the answers :) The reason I was doubtful was that that I do not know how a genetic algorithm might model (-1,0,1), and whether there is actually a better model out there.

Comment: If you do that there are only $3^p$ possible parameter estimates. Why not just try all of them and see which maximizes the likelihood? (Unless $p$ is very large??)

Comment: Since I have additional constraints, I actually think that in my case it would work to do an exhaustive search. You guys made me realize it is not only (-1,0,1), but it could also be a fourth option: force y to be 0, *regardless of all other output*. No clue how I would model the fourth option.

Comment: I think it means the presence of a variable would be like a gate cutting off the coefficient for a further layer. Maybe a neural network would be good for that, but then I again will need to be able to force coefficients to be (-1,0,1)

Comment: @PascalvKooten, wouldn't that correspond to the case where every coefficient was zero???

Answer (score 2):

This kind of *equally weighted* models [was studied in the past](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162156/when-do-improper-linear-models-get-robustly-beautiful) (e.g. Wainer, 1976). Since you have only three possible values of parameters, then with $K$ predictors, you have $3^K$ number of combinations of parameter values. Unless you have a huge number of parameters, then you could use exhaustive search over all possible combinations of parameters and then pick the best solution according to some loss function of your choice. With larger number of parameters, you could use some kind of optimization algorithm (e.g. genetic) to find the best solution for you.

---

Wainer, Howard (1976). [Estimating coefficients in linear models: It don't make no nevermind](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~hwainer/Readings/Wainer_Estimating%20Coefficients%20in%20Linear%20Models.pdf). *Psychological Bulletin 83*(2), 213.

Comment: I'm not really understanding from the paper how I could limit the choice of coefficients to (-1,0,1), though it is interesting to see something related.

Comment: @PascalvKooten because it does not say anything about constraining parameters, it's an example os using equally weighted models as described by you.